Why am I getting this derivation of time period of pendulum in an accelerated frame wrong?

We are working in the frame of the cart and we are trying to obtain the $\tau=k\theta$ form.
So, let's write the $\tau=I_{axis}\alpha$ first for a small deviation $\theta$ from the vartical.
(The moment of inertia of the bob about the point of suspension would approximately be equal to $ml^2$ as the bob is small.)
Thus,
$mgl\sin\theta - mal\cos\theta=ml^2\alpha$
As $\theta$ is small, $$gl\theta-al=l^2 \alpha$$
Solving this would give $T=2π\sqrt{\frac{l}{g}}$ and not $T=2π\sqrt{\frac{l}{g_{eff}}}$
What am I doing wrong?

starting with the free body diagram

obtain the sum of the torques about point A
$$\sum \tau=m\,L^2\ddot\theta+m\,g\,L\,\sin(\theta)-
m\,a_a\,L\,\cos(\theta)=0$$
from here with $~\theta=\theta_0+\phi~$
$$\,L^2\ddot\phi+\,g\,L\,\sin(\theta_0+\phi)-
\,a_a\,L\,\cos(\theta_0+\phi)=0\tag 2$$
linearized equation (2) with
$$\sin(\theta_0+\phi)=\sin \left( \theta_{{0}} \right) \cos \left( \phi \right) +\cos
 \left( \theta_{{0}} \right) \sin \left( \phi \right) \\
\cos(\theta_0+\phi)=\cos \left( \theta_{{0}} \right) \cos \left( \phi \right) -\sin
 \left( \theta_{{0}} \right) \sin \left( \phi \right)
\\
\sin(\phi)=\phi~,\cos(\phi)=1
$$
$$L^2\ddot\phi+
 \left( g\,L\cos \left( \theta_{{0}} \right) +a_{{0}}L\sin \left( \theta
_{{0}} \right)  \right) \phi +g\,L\sin \left( 
\theta_{{0}} \right) -a_{{0}}L\cos \left( \theta_{{0}} \right)  
=0\tag 3$$
for $~\ddot\phi=0~,\phi=0~$ you obtain $~\theta_0=
\arctan\left(\frac{a_0}{g}\right)$
thus equation (3)
$$\ddot\phi+\omega\,\phi=0\quad,\omega=\frac{\sqrt{a_0^2+g^2}}{L}$$

Since the equilibrium angle $\theta_0=\arctan\frac{a_0}{g}\neq0$ has now changed, you cannot assume $\theta$ is small. Instead, you can define a shifted angle $\varphi:=\theta-\theta_0$, and use the small-angle approximation on this instead (i.e. Taylor expand around $\theta_0$ rather than $0$).

Thanks! I was assuming that it won't matter as the angle would be small at some point in the motion. Is the $\theta$ in $\tau=k\theta$ should necessarily be from the mean position?

Yep, because then it represents a restoring force around some equilibrium (compare to Hooke's Law). Then it's meaningful to talk about small oscillations, around that equilibrium.
